# Unir 2 imagenes en Java

Tags: java

Buenas, estoy intentando unir 2 imágenes en java, una de ellas es un numero que esta en una imagen y la otra es un fondo en negro con un pequeño hueco blanco para poner el numero, me gustaría saber si es posible colocar ese numero en el hueco y luego guardar la imagen, gracias!
Ejemplo:

Tengo este código de barras:

[image: Codigo]

Y, lo tengo que colocar en esta imagen:

[image: Imagen 2]

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir el código que tienes hasta el momento por favor?

Comment: No tengo ningún código hasta ahora, solo tengo 2 imágenes en png y, quiero unirlas

Comment: Es que, sinceramente, con el enunciado que tienes hasta ahora no entiendo muy bien lo que quieres realizar.

Comment: Intenta primero resolverlo tu mismo, utilizando BufferedImage, por que tu pregunta dificilmente tendrá respuestas, y van a ponerla en espera.

Cuando tengas un código con el cual se explique mejor lo que deseas hacer, con gusto podremos apoyarte

Comment: Buenas, he actualizado el post, ahora quizás os hagáis una mejor idea de lo que quiero, gracias!

Comment: Hola @fer112233. Ayuda bastante ver la imagen de lo que estás intentando hacer. Sin embargo no me queda claro: ¿Siempre sería en la misma posición o podrías calcularlo una vez para que siempre lo inserte en un (x,y) fijo? ¿o se debe analizar cuál es el sector en blanco? ¿Qué investigaste e intentaste hasta ahora? ¿Podrías agregar el código por más que no esté funcionando?

Comment: Buenas Mariano, no he encontrado nada sobre ello por lo que, aún no he obtenido ningún avance en cuanto a código respecta. Si, sería siempre en el mismo lugar, Gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Podemos usar BufferedImage para hacer la combinación

```
BufferedImage biUno= ImageIO.read(new File("uno.png"));
BufferedImage biDos = ImageIO.read(new File("dos.png"));


BufferedImage biResultado = new BufferedImage(1024, 256, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB); //suponiendo tamaño de imagen  y ARGB que soporta trasparencia

Graphics g = biResultado.getGraphics();
g.drawImage(biUno, 0, 0, null); //se rellena con imagen uno
g.drawImage(biDos, 5, 5, null); //se rellena con imagen dos con  un supuesto margen de 5 (habria que ver cual es el real)


ImageIO.write(biResultado, "PNG", new File("resultado.png"));
```

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte, intentare usar este método :)